# If every subset of a language L is regular then L is regular?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

I know that converse of above theorem is not true i.e if L is regular then every subset of L need not be regular

Comment: You mean, every proper subset? Otherwise it's trivially true.

Comment: how? can you plz explain.

Comment: Every language is a subset of itself. Thus, if every subset of the language is regular, then the subset that is the language itself is regular as well, and thus the language itself is regular.

Comment: Not just that, if every proper subset of a language is regular, then the language is finite (and thus regular).

Comment: ya.. i got it:) what about every proper subset?

Comment: i think it is not the case. For example every proper subset of a^nb^n is regular but a^nb^n is not regular

Comment: I disagree what about "`a^pb^p` where `p` is a prime"? It is a proper subset of `a^nb^n` and it's definitely not regular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only

> if every subset of a language L is regular then L is regular

but also

> if every proper subset of a language L is regular, then L is finite

**Proof:**

This is equivalent to the statement

> if a language `L` is infinite, then it contains a subset that is not a regular language.

The pumping lemma for regular languages states that "there exists a length `l` such that if a word `w` in the language is longer than `l`, then there exist three words `x,y,z` such that `y` is non-empty, `xyz == w` and every `xy^nz` is in the language".

If a language is infinite and regular, then it contains a word longer than any given length. Thus, there neccessarily exist three words `x,y,z` such that every `xy^nz` is in the language.

Now, every proper subset of `{xy^nz; n in N}` is a proper subset of `L`. Now, there definitely exist proper subsets of `xy^nz` that are not regular*. Thus, every regular infinite language has a proper subset that is not regular.

If a language is infinite and not regular, then consider any of its proper infinite subsets. If the subset is not regular, then the language is not a counter-example. If the subset is regular, then use the previous paragraph to find a proper subset that is not regular. Since being a proper subset is transitive, this subset is a proper subset of the original language, and the language is not a counter-example.

Thus, every infinite language has a proper subset that is not regular.

Thus, if every proper subset of a language is regular, then the language is finite (and thus regular).

QED

*For example, the set `{xy^{n^2}z; n in N}` is a proper subset of `{xy^nz; n in N}` and it is not regular, as shown by the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill-Nerode_theorem).